# error: unknown option '--story-format=csf-ts'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

This error occurred while initializing a storybook cli.

```
npx -p @storybook/cli sb init --story-format=csf-ts
```

Error below:

```
error: unknown option '--story-format=csf-ts'
```

Let me know solution.